# Angular $compile for dynamic content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-compile, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.5

Using Angular 1.5, I want to use a generic "overlay" component to display other components within a modal. I'd like to pass in other components to be rendered within the overlay.

I thought I could use $compile in my controller, but the component does not render:

In my controller:

```
ctrl.appendComponent = function(component_type) {
    ctrl.$content.empty(); // this is the overlay element
    var component = '<' + component_type + '></' + component_type + '>';
    ctrl.$content.append($compile(component)($scope));
};
```

I've created the component I want to pass in, for example "foo" and get only an empty element in the DOM:

```
<foo></foo>
```

Even though, in the template for foo component, I have:

```
<h1>header</h1>
<p>body</p>
```

And expect to see:

```
<foo>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <p>body</p>
</foo>
```

Comment: What is `$content`? Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably as a fiddle/plunk.

Comment: Also how did you create the component? using 1.5 component(.. or with .directive(.. with replace:true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, but it looks like you are doing the same thing. I would suggest simplifying your code, it may be the case that something is not returning what you think it is.

```
                link: function(scope, iElem, tAttrs){
                            var html = "<div>hello</div>";

                            var content = $compile(html)(scope);
                            iElem.append(content);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks @Darin. After reviewing my code, I realized that I'd defined the component I was passing in using kebab-case instead of camel-case:

`App.component('foo-bar', ... `
instead of:
`App.component('fooBar', ... `